# How do I open a Prism window from a non-prism WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I'm working on a big WPF project without Prism library. Now I received a new small project that uses Prism and consists in a couple of views only (MainWindow and a dialog). Is there a way to import it in my solution as a new assembly and launch its MainWindow clicking a button from my non-prism project part?

Comment: The window to open is in a separate assembly.

Comment: If this is really just a view and a dialog, it might be easier to just put those into your project directly.

Comment: Well yes, but if there's a proper way I'd prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work unless the small project uses the (prematurely deprecated) bootstrapper.

To configure the container and create the initial window, Prism nowadays uses a custom `System.Windows.App`-derived type. There can only be one instance of these in any app-domain.

You can go for a separate process or a separate app-domain or a refactoring to introduce your own bootstrapper.

If you *had* a bootstrapper, all you needed to do was `new MyBootstrapper().Run();`